# Slick2D: Changing mouse sensitivity changes cursor x/y positions

Tags: java, window, mouse, slick2d

I am currently building a test game where I can attempt to create certain effects that happen in games, such as changing the mouse sensitivity when the user changes a value in the settings. Firstly, let me clarify that all this is done in Java using Slick2D and lwjgl.

Now that that's out of the way, I need to tell you how my mouse appears on the screen. Since I will be playing around with the mouse movement, I decided to hide the native mouse with `Mouse.setGrabbed(true);` in my `init{}` method, grab a 32x32 cursor image from the web, and tie the cursor image x/y coordinates to the native mouse coordinates so it now appears as the native mouse. Here is how it was done:

```
int xpos = Math.max(Math.min(Mouse.getX(), 945), 4);
int ypos = Math.max(Math.min(Mouse.getY(), 572), 23);
```

This all just means that `4< xpos< 945` and that `23< ypos<572` so the cursor stays within the bounds of my window (not really important information but nevertheless I decided to include it).

Let's get to the problem. At the "default" state of the mouse, it's tied to the coordinates of the native mouse as said above. So the cursor is rendered like so:

```
cursor.draw(xpos, 640 - ypos);
```

(640 - ypos is needed because the mouse coordinates sprout from the bottom left) now, when the user goes into the settings of the game and changes the mouse sensitivity higher, for example, 8 times higher than the usual speed, I rendered the cursor coordinates like so (only the x sensitivity is multiplied to facilitate testing):

```
if(settingsSens == 0){
xpos = Math.max(Math.min(Mouse.getX()*8-28, 945), 4); //This means that 4< xpos< 945 so the image always stay within the window
cursor.draw(xpos, 640 - ypos);
}
```

with settingsSens being the boolean of the mouse sensitivity change in the settings. What happens is that the cursor image doesn't go out of the window since its xpos is restrained inside of it, but the coordinates seem to go out... It's really hard to explain: it looks like the image stays but the coordinates leave, so if you move your mouse way to the right the cursor stops on the right side of the window, when you try to bring it back the cursor stays "glued" on the right side of the window until the x coordinates reach 945, at which point the cursor will move to the left again and detach from the right side of the window. I would like to stop this!

All I'm looking for is changing the sensitivity of the mouse without having the cursor change position after the change. Because as of now, once you change the sensitivity and come back, since xpos is multiplied by 8 the coordinates are way out of the window and not at the old position where xpos use to be at the normal speed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is a proper bounding for your coordinates, since you need to apply the sensitivity modification when calculating `xPos` and `yPos` and not when drawing the mouse.

I strongly suggest you extract the calculation logic for the x and y coordinates properly into a separate method, encapsulating sensitivity and bounding for one coordinate at a time, like so:

```
static int boundedCoordinate(int coordinate, int sensitivity, int maximum, int minimum) {
    // 4 < xpos < 945
    int result = coordinate * sensitivity;
    result = Math.max(minimum, result);
    result = Math.min(maximum, result);
}
```

And then for your drawing loop, go for something like:

```
cursor.draw(boundedCoordinate(xPos, sensitivity, X_MAXIMUM, X_MINIMUM),
    boundedCoordinate(yPos, sensitivity, Y_MAXIMUM, Y_MINIMUM));
```

Comment: Ok I see, so you suggest that I multiply the xPos and yPos by the sensitivity factor before I draw the mouse? (Java is getting mad at me with "Pair")

Comment: @MrGreenJam This should be more obvious... Pair is just a gimmick I use to avoid returning arrays when I need to return multiple results from a method

Comment: Okay, I see. Right so what I did was multiple xpos by 8 before drawing which kinda works?.. So the cursor image doesn't go out of the window, which is awesome, but.. It's really hard to explain: it looks like the image stays but the coordinates leave, so if you move your mouse way to the right the cursor stops on the right side of the window, when you try to bring it back the cursor stays on the right side of the window until the x coordinate reaches 945 at which point the cursor will move to the left again and detach from the right side of the window.

Comment: @MrGreenJam correct. Unfortunately I wouldn't know how exactly to fix that, since I have no experience with capturing the Mouse. That's a somewhat more complicated problem :)

Comment: Indeed, well thanks for your input! I'll wait a bit more in hopes of a hero that can save me from this troublesome experience that I like to call "being stuck", sorry... I'm a bit tired, thanks again!